# What are Promises in MongoDB?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, promise

I am currently working on a project with mongoDB and am receiving this notification in the terminal:

"DeprecationWarning: Mongoose: mpromise (mongoose's default promise library) is deprecated, plug in your own promise library instead: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/promises.html"

I am fairly new to mongo and have no idea what these "promises" are. I also checked out the link in the notification, but still cannot understand what it is saying.

If someone could please explain what "promises" are within mongodb and what I should do about this deprecation, that would be great. Thanks!

Comment: The linked article is really quite clear about this. What, specifically, don't you understand?

Comment: Promises deal with async operations. They are wrappers for values that are not available yet. They are not a mongodb specific thing, actually that's what this message is about, that they deprecated their implementation of this pattern, and want you to plug in a more sophisticated/performant implementation. imo. [Q](https://github.com/kriskowal/q) and [bluebird](http://bluebirdjs.com) have set the bar, but nowadays every Browser and Nodejs provides a basic Promise implementation. Just google the topic, there are plenty of articles.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I just don't understand what exactly a promise is. Now I get that they are similar to callbacks

Comment: @Thomas Thanks Thomas! This helps a ton

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Promises in MongoDB are just like promises in the larger JS ecosystem. They are an alternative to callback functions which allow for step-by-step orderly execution of asynchronous code.

As your Mongo link, shows, for example, you can use Promise.then() instead of a callback function.

Here is [some further discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38424517/es5-vs-es6-promises).

Here are some other promise implementations:

1. [Bluebird](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/why-promises.html)
2. [jQuery](https://api.jquery.com/promise/)
3. [Native ES6/ES2015+ Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I appreciate it!