# Why lib.es5.d.ts has Promise?

Tags: typescript, promise, ecmascript-5

ES5 did not have `Promise`, see for example https://stackoverflow.com/a/38424561. However, TypeScript library for ES5 contains `Promise` definition: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/lib/lib.es5.d.ts#L1416. Why?

Comment: This seems like a better question to ask on https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues than Stack Overflow.

Comment: They recommend asking questions on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

The `lib.es5.d.ts` only declares the `Promise` *interface* (and also the `PromiseLike` "thenable" interface and the `PromiseConstructorLike` type), which are pretty useful and not tied to any specific ES release.

It does *not* declare a global `var Promise` or the native `Promise` constructor and its static methods.

Comment: Technically, if they are not tied to a ES release, they should be declared in a separate file, like `lib.promises.d.ts`, not a specific ES version release file like `lib.es5.d.ts`...

Comment: @HereticMonkey That's true. No idea why it wasn't done like that, probably just nobody bothered to do it. Apparently `lib.es5.d.ts` serves as the sink for all "standard library" stuff (including utilities like `Partial` and so on), and is included in all other `lib.…` versions by reference.